# Entity Framework - Complex Query Best Practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t-sql, entity-framework-4.1

In a multilingual database, I have the following tables:

- Area & AreaLocale: Area contains Latitude/Longitude/AreaId & AreaLocale contains Id/Name/Description/AreaId/CultureId
- Country & CountryLocale: Country contains Latitude/Longitude/CountryId & CountryLocale contains Id/Name/Description/CountryId/CultureId
- Culture: Contains Id/Name/DisplayName

Now, what I need is to retrieve is the following:

AreaId/Name/Description/Longitude/Latitude/CountryId/Country Name/CultureId/Culture Display Name, such that Area's IsDeleted = false.

The following query is written:

```
var q = (from areas in context.Areas
 join countries in context.Countries on areas.CountryId equals countries.CountryId
 join arealocales in context.AreaLocales on areas.AreaId equals arealocales.AreaId
 join cultures in context.Cultures on arealocales.CultureId equals cultures.CultureId
 join countrylocales in context.CountryLocales on areas.CountryId equals countrylocales.CountryId
 where areas.IsDeleted == false
 select new Area()
 {
      CountryId = areas.CountryId,
      CountryName = countrylocales.Name,
      CultureId = cultures.CultureId,
      CultureDisplayName = cultures.DisplayName,
                          Description = arealocales.Description,
      Id = areas.AreaId,
      Latitude = areas.Latitude,
      Longitude = areas.Longitude,
      Name = arealocales.Name
 }).ToList();
```

Is there a better way in writing the above query rather than using Joins and use UnionAll instead?

Comment: Don't you have navigation properties in your model, such as `public ICollection<AreaLocale> AreaLocales { get; set; }` and `public Country Country { get; set; }` in `Area` class, etc? If you had these you won't need any hand-written joins at all.

Comment: In fact, I have the following: List of AreaLocales on Area, country property on Area entity, and List of CountryLocale on Country. How would achieve same thing as above? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering to your comment:

> In fact, I have the following: List of AreaLocales on Area, country
>   property on Area entity, and List of CountryLocale on Country.

I'm also assuming that `AreaLocale` has a `Culture` property (because you apparently have a `CultureId` property on the `AreaLocale` class):

```
var q = (from area in context.Areas
         where area.IsDeleted == false
         select new   // or: select new SomeHelperClass
         {
             Id = area.AreaId,
             Latitude = area.Latitude,
             Longitude = area.Longitude,
             CountryId = area.CountryId,

             AreaLocales = area.AreaLocales.Select(areaLocale => new
             {
                 Description = areaLocale.Description,
                 Name = areaLocale.Name,
                 CultureId = areaLocale.Culture.CultureId,
                 CultureDisplayName = areaLocale.Culture.DisplayName
             }),

             CountryNames = area.Country.Countrylocales.Select(
                 countryLocale => countryLocale.Name)
         })
        .ToList();
```

The result objects have two nested lists four the AreaLocales and the CountryNames. If these are almost all properties of the classes anyway you also could just use eager loading:

```
var q = (from area in context.Areas
             .Include(a => a.AreaLocales.Select(al => al.Culture))
             .Include(a => a.Country.CountryLocales)
         where area.IsDeleted == false
         select area)
        .ToList();
```

Entity Framework will create the necessary joins when these LINQ queries are translated into SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the impressive answer. I am trying to understand the details above. The above query would return Area columns + AreaLocale collection per Area. As for the CountryNames, each Area has one country, so I assume the CountryNames will include all locales of a single Country that is attached to Area, right? 

Any good resources on understanding EF, how to write queries against it?  Thanks

Comment: One more question, if I want to filter out data based on Country & Culture, I would add a .Where() to AreaLocales & another one to CountryNames?

Comment: @bhaidar: Yes, your understanding in your first comment is correct. And yes, you can add a `Where` in the first example to filter subobjects, but not in the second example (inside of `Include`) because eager loading doesn't allow filtering of the included properties. Good introduction to EF 4.1 is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot Slauma! appreciated.